# Named Range String limitations

Tags: vba, excel, named-ranges

I recently tried to add named ranges using a self-written function. While playing around with the names I found out that it is not possible for some reason to add names such "nam3" or "3nam" while "name3" is allowed for example.

Can someone explain to me why it seems that there is a restriction when using just three chars in combination with one number? Or is this behaviour caused by another circumstance I didn't recognize?

Here's my simplified code:

```
Public Sub addNames()
Dim readNames()
Dim i As Integer
Dim rng As Range

readNames = Range("rngNames").value

For i = LBound(readNames, 1) To UBound(readNames, 1)
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(i, i), Cells(i + 1, i + 1))
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=readNames(i, 1), RefersTo:=rng
Next i

End Sub
```

[ExcelTestSheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1k2vZ.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To address `nam3` and `3nam` as names ranges:

> - nam3 is not allowed because it is a cell address (i.e. column `NAM` and row `3`)
> - 3nam is not allowed because named ranges cannot start with numbers

Stick to [these rules](http://www.contextures.com/xlNames01.html#rules) and you'll be fine:

> [image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would vote it if I could but I'm new here so need exp. first. Now I understand my mistake as I had "TEL1" as a name and this one also refers to colum TEL and row 1 :'D

Wow thanks!